# How to create a deformable/bendable pipe/glue-gun-stick like cylinder shaped object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, rigging, bezier-curves

I want to create a deformable/bendable pipe/glue-gun-stick like cylinder shaped object which I can fix at one end and hold the other end to bend it in any direction. I don't want to create a body of multiple rigid joints. I want to use it as a physical object in unity. I want to use inverse kinematics and use strings to pull one end of the cylinder to bend it in the corresponding direction.

Here I used the top hooks to bend the cylinder but I want to use the bottom bones (hooks) to pull the thick strings which should bend the cylinder in that direction. 
But this is not happening:

[image]

The string just gets stretched.
I've uploaded a video here https://youtu.be/zOQmk0ZdlGE also showing this if that helps:

Comment: Could you post some reference images of what you want to achieve? What have you got so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You could do it with a curve in blender but to export to unity I expect you will need to use a mesh object and armature.

Comment: "which I can fix at one end and hold the other end to bend it in any direction." ...Okay, well without knowing how that is done in Unity it's hard to know how to help you. On the Blender side of things, I can explain how to create the topology and the rig, but it sounds like you don't want to rig it ("I don't want to create a body of multiple rigid joints") and you have some other method in mind that is specific to Unity. Maybe [Game Dev SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask your question.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I have updated the question adding some media. Thank you for responding.

Comment: @sambler What do you think of the current object? Will this work in unity in your opinion? Thank you for responding.

Comment: @Mentalist I've updated the question adding some media of my current object. I've updated my question also. I hope I can progress in the right direction from here. What is your opinion?

Comment: The images you added are helpful for understanding what you want to do. If I am understanding correctly, I think instead of "strings" try bones that span the length of the string mesh, and scale those bones. Make the child of each be an IK target that doesn't inherit scale. I'm sorry I don't have time to put together an example now, but hopefully you understand what I mean.